# Are there variations of DDR4 DIMM modules that are pin-incompatible?

Tags: memory

This question is motivated by the previous history of DDR2 unbuffered/buffered memory being [physically incompatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Relative_speed_comparison_between_similar_modules) due to the position of the notch.

From what I understand, DDR4 UDIMM (unbuffered) is in fact pin-compatible with RDIMM (buffered) memory. Would someone please confirm this by personal experience or reference?

Are there any instances where server memory for DDR4 is physically incompatible, for example, voltage specifications, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The notch is not the problem, it will be if your BIOS/Mainboard support it mainly.

A lot of low end or consomers mainboard don’t support buffered memory.

As an example tried to upgrade my home pc with leftover RDIMM DDR4, only one of my two PC BIOS accepted it.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. The question is asking specifically about physical compatibility.

Comment: @Zhro Yes it’s, as I wouldnt be able to use a buffered dimm in a home computer